# これは" 過学習" 現象なのでしょうか？

Tags: 機械学習, 深層学習

構成の異なるNeural Network(NN)AとBを同じ訓練データ(batch)で同時に訓練していく場合,いつも前半ではBの推論精度がAより非常に良いのですが、途中からBの進化の速度がダウンしてだんだん推論精度がAに抜かれてしまう現象です。

下記のような３つのoptimizerを同じ訓練ループの中で試しています 。

```py
## 一つ目
optimizer = AdaBound( model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, betas=(0.9, 0.999), final_lr=0.1, gamma=1e-3, eps=1e-8, weight_decay=0, amsbound=False) 


## 二つ目
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam( model.parameters(), lr=0.001, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08, weight_decay=0, amsgrad=True,# amsgrad=True : gradの大小によってlearninig rate自動調整機能：試してみるべき。 foreach=None, maximize=False, capturable=False, differentiable=False, fused=False)

## 三つ目
optimizer = torch.optim.NAdam( model.parameters(), lr=0.002, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08, weight_decay=0, momentum_decay=0.004, foreach=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

過学習かどうかはテストデータで判断することが一般的かと思います。
質問文のみでは情報が少なくて断定はできませんが、質問者さんの「過学習」に対する認識が違うように思われます。（質問文からですと学習率の違いが訓練課程に影響していそうですが）
[詰め込みすぎて使えない？過学習の落とし穴](https://www.mitsubishielectric.co.jp/corporate/special/hello-ai/words/kagakusyu.html#:%7E:text=%E3%80%8C%E9%81%8E%E5%AD%A6%E7%BF%92%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81,%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%92%E6%8C%87%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82)

質問の両モデルについてもテストデータで正解率等を比べないとどちらもモデルが優れているかも判断できないかと思いますよ。

Comment: お回答ありがとうございます。　学習率と一番関係していますね。
けれども、現状として２つのNNにそれぞれ三種類のoptimizer(同じ種類のoptimizerに同じ lr を設定)で
同一訓練batchデータ発生ループの中で訓練をさせ、どのopimizerの下でも前記現象が起きたので、可能性としてBのパラメータ数が多すぎる原因かな？

Comment: NNの設定条件を質問に追記されますとより良い回答がつきやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: merinoさん　ありがとうございます❣

下記のような３つのoptimizerを同じ訓練ループの中で試しています

一番目：

optimizer = AdaBound(
            model.parameters(), 
            lr=1e-3, 
            betas=(0.9, 0.999), 
            final_lr=0.1, 
            gamma=1e-3,
            eps=1e-8, 
            weight_decay=0, 
            amsbound=False)

Comment: 二番目：

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
          model.parameters(), 
          lr=0.001, 
          betas=(0.9, 0.999),
          eps=1e-08, 
          weight_decay=0, 
          amsgrad=True,# amsgrad=True : gradの大小によってlearninig rate自動調整機能：試してみるべき。
          foreach=None, 
          maximize=False, 
          capturable=False, 
          differentiable=False, 
          fused=False)

Comment: 三番目：
optimizer = torch.optim.NAdam(
          model.parameters(),
          lr=0.002, 
          betas=(0.9, 0.999), 
          eps=1e-08, 
          weight_decay=0, 
          momentum_decay=0.004, 
          foreach=None)

Comment: best medicineさんへ
追記はこちらの欄ではなく”質問本文”へお願いします。そうすることで他の回答者・有識者の方の目につきやすくなり有用な回答が得られやすくなると思います。⇒ 今回は私の方で編集させていただきました。